# PHP inside echo

Tags: php, html, echo

Here is my code

```
echo "<div class="navigation"><p><?php posts_nav_link(); ?></p></div> </div><!-- #content -->";
```

But I get error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ','`

How do I correct this code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### You have multiple options

**Escape your double quotes**

You're not escaping your quotes. Your code thinks that it stops at the first `"` at the beginning of `"navigation"`.

```
echo "<div class=\"navigation\"><p><?php posts_nav_link(); ?></p></div> </div><!-- #content -->";
```

**Concatenate, either using a period or sprintf()**

Yes, you *can* concatenate your strings. Here's a nicer option. Check out [sprintf()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php).

```
sprintf('<div class="navigation"><p>%s</p></div>', posts_nav_link());
```

**Use single outer quotes instead**

Alternatively, you can use **single quotes** instead ;)

```
echo '<div class="navigation"><p><?php posts_nav_link(); ?></p></div> </div><!-- #content -->';
```

**Finally, the best way**

And finally... why don't you end your PHP, write your HTML normally, then put your PHP in there where it should be?

```
// your php code...
?>

<div class="navigation">
    <p>
        <?php posts_nav_link(); ?>
    </p>
</div>

<div><!-- Content --></div>

<?php
// Continue your PHP
```

The latter option is much nicer in your views, imho.

Comment: IMHO it's not a good usage of `sprintf`. You can doesn't mean you should :-)
Good work for your answer though.

Comment: Thanks. Of course, it's just there as an option ;) I have never used `sprintf()` personally for function calls, only scalar types. Still, I *really* like it, for some reason...

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just `concatenate` strings and varibales with dots `.` and escape properly your double quotes `\"`

```
echo "<div class=\"navigation\"><p>". posts_nav_link() ."</p></div> </div><!-- #content -->";
                //^escape    ^    //^concatenate     //^concatenate
```

Answer (score 1):

1) You can use `.`. to concatenate hard-coded string to a value returned by a function.
2) you must escape the double quote in your string.

```
echo "<div class=\"navigation\"><p>" . posts_nav_link() . 
"</p></div> </div><!-- #content -->";
```